# Export library module as apk with android studio

Tags: android, export, android-studio, apk, android-library

Is there any possibility to export a library project as an apk file in android studio?

Normally you could run a project and the apk is created automatically, but not with library projects

Comment: Library Projects are not for the purpose which you are thinking

Comment: Yes you are right, but in my case it´s a plugin which gets later loaded by a ClassLoader

Comment: you can export your android library project as .aar file which contains resources files and everything you want which is in apk. aar is generated at '<yourlibroot>/libs/build/yourlib.aar'

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to export a library project as an apk file in android studio?

No. It is also not possible to export a library project as an APK file in Eclipse, any other IDE, or the command line. Android library projects do not create APK files.

> in my case it´s a plugin which gets later loaded by a ClassLoader

Then it is not an Android library project.

Comment: What else could it then be?

Comment: @Nachbar90: An Android library project is a compile-time construct, designed to allow other developers to reuse code and Android resources. A `ClassLoader` does not address resources, and so using an Android library project is pointless. I don't play the plugin-with-`ClassLoader` game, because it usually results in a security hole big enough to drive a truck through. If I had to guess, you probably need to make a regular (non-library) project, so you can use `DexClassLoader` with the resulting APK.

Comment: Thank you, so I´ll try to convert my library project to a normal android project.Yes, maybe I´ll find any other solution for my case than classloading.